# How to find Sum of differences of maximum and minimum of all possible subset of an array

Tags: java, arrays

**how to Find sum of  maximum- minimum of all possible  subset of given array**

for example

**given array is 1**
all posible subsets are [[], [1]]
1-1=0

**given array is 1 2**
all posible subsets are [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
   1-1+2-2+2-1=1

**given array is 1 2 3**
all posible subsets are [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
1-1+2-2+2-1+3-3+3-1+3-2+3-1=6

**given array is 1 2 3 4**
all posible subsets are [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
 ans=23

**given array is 2 3 4 5** 
all posible subsets are [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5], [3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
 ans= 72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, sort the array then the i'th element will be minimum in all subsets that do not include the `i-1` first elements, and include this element. There will be `2^(n-i)` of those. In the same way, `i` will be the highest element in each subset that does not include any number after `i`, and include `i`, and there are `2^(i-1)` such subsets.now iterate and for each `i` add:

```
sum = sum + array[i] * (2^(i) - 2^(n-i-1))
//if array starts with index array[0]
```

Consider your example: `[1,2,3]`

```
sorted=1,2,3
1* (2^0 - 2^2) + 2*(2^1 - 2^1) + 3*(2^2 - 2^0) =
1*(-3) + 2*0 + 3*(3) = -3 + 0 + 9 = 6
```

Comment: plz explain little bit more..explantion is very hard to get.

Comment: will this formula works when array are non consecutive for e.g 1 3 5 6 7 11

Comment: and what about repeated values  1 3 3 4 5 6 7 7

Comment: actualy the question is Given a set S of N non-negative integers (Some integers might occur more than once in the set), find out the value of SETDIFF(S).
setdif= sum of max(s)-min(s)
Where max(s) represents the maximum value in set s whereas min(s) represents the minimum value in the set s.
As value of SETDIFF(S) can be very large, print it modulo (109 + 7) .

Comment: See... This site gives u idea but not code .. U can Accept the answer if idea was helpful ..

Comment: seeing your formula & discription know i am easily able to understand your logic which is 100% correct...but at that time when i asked i was unable to understand a single line of your explanation because of my weak knowledge of sets ...
votes up for YOU