# Sum of OR of smallest and largest elements of each subset of a set

Tags: algorithm, set, subset, logical-operators

Given a set S, for its each non-empty subset, find smallest and largest elements and take their logical OR. Find sum of these ORs across all such subsets.

For example: S = {1, 2, 3}, then subsets

{1} smallest=1 largest=1 OR=1

{2} smallest=2 largest=2 OR=2

{3} smallest=3 largest=3 OR=3

{1, 2} smallest=1 largest=2 OR=3

{2, 3} smallest=2 largest=3 OR=3

{1, 3} smallest=1 largest=3 OR=3

{1, 2, 3} smallest=1 largest=3 OR=3

Answer is 18.

I have read [How to find Sum of differences of maximum and minimum of all possible subset of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136347/how-to-find-sum-of-differences-of-maximum-and-minimum-of-all-possible-subset-of) but not able to use that logic here.

Comment: You need to get all possible combination and do OR? You don't you write brute force first

Comment: An algorithm would be meant to be implemented in code. Since different languages provide different tools, it would be helpful to know which language you have in mind.

Comment: Choose any two elements from the set, take their logical OR. Count the elements between those two. Determine how many sets can be made from those N+2 elements. Multiply. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm

- Sort the input data
- Loop from `i = 0 to n` where n is the length of the input, and `j = i to n`, Since the input is sorted `input[i]` will be smallest and `input[j]` will be the largest in the range `[i,j]`
- Now that we know that `input[i]` is the lowest and `input[j]` is the largest we also know that there are `j - i -1` middle elements of the array whose combinations will result in the same lowest and largest values hence we multiple the `OR` of the low and high with the total number of permutations possible with these middle numbers.
- For ex. For `input = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `i = 0` and `j = 3` i.e.) `lowest = 1` and `largest = 4` we know the elements `[2, 3]` can appear in the subsets without changing the lowest and largest value. `[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]` are all valid. The number of combinations possible with the middle elements are `2 ^ (count of middle elements)`.
- Repeat this for all lowest and largest pair.

Here is the code in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    vector<int> input {3, 2, 1};
    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    int answer = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j=i; j < input.size(); ++j)
        {
            int elements = (j - i) - 1;
            int multiple = elements > 0 ? pow(2, elements) : 1;
            answer += ((input[i] | input[j]) * multiple);
            cout << input[i] << ' ' << input[j] << ' ' << answer << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout <<  answer <<endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get any better than `O(n^2)`. This effectively is down from `O(2^n)`